# SharePoint Onine List as Datasource to Excel Services / Business Intelligence in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, sql-server, excel, excel-services, business-intelligence

Trying to join 2 SharePoint Custom Lists sources into an excel  Services Graph.

If so, any BI option for formating list data on an SPO page?

Possible now under SPO 2013 A3 license?

Confused about the Refresh issue point in the first link.

http://office.microsoft.com/client/15/help/preview?AssetId=HA104054002&lcid=1033&NS=SPOStandard&Version=15&CTT=5&origin=HA104093144

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198236.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn394343.aspx